# How can I label every line in a multiple regression plot neatly without overlapping?

Tags: r, ggplot2, labeling

I am trying to label each line in my regression plot in ** R ** based on the country the line corresponds to but I'm running into excess labels and labels that are not situated where I would like them. I want the label for each line to be off to the left of each line. I used the check_overlap function but, the labels are still overlapping.

This is a link to the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14lZajSHqDvDswot8tFh5x6XOAMfmqFkEKZnvsDc_t0c/edit?usp=sharing
The datasheet here is what I call "urban" in my code! No manipulation is needed!

This is the code that I tried:

```
Fig1a <- urban %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = log10(B15), y = log10(E_GR_AH14), color = CTR_MN_NM)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = FALSE) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1:1, color = "black", size = 1) +
  labs(y="log Total High Greenness km2", x="log Total Built Area km2", title = "Total Built Area vs. Total High Greenness") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Argentina"="#fb6542",
                                "Australia"="#3f681c",
                                "Brazil"="#fb6542",
                                "Canada"="#fb6542",
                                "Germany"="#3f681c",
                                "France"="#3f681c",
                                "United Kingdom"="#fb6542",
                                "Indonesia"="#fb6542",
                                "India"="#3f681c",
                                "Nigeria"="#3f681c",
                                "United States"="#375E97",
                                "South Africa"="#3f681c",
                                "Japan"="#3f681c",
                                "Mexico"="#375E97",
                                "Russia"="#3f681c",
                                "Ukraine"="#375E97",
                                "Bangladesh"="#fb6542",
                                "China"="#375E97"))+ 
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(aes(label = CTR_MN_NM), nudge_x = 0.2, nudge_y = 0.2, check_overlap = TRUE)
```

I expected to at least get a concise number of labels but the labels doubled and are all over the place and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for sharing data and code with your question. To get help, you might want to include some code that shows how you read in the data from the linked file and get it ready for plotting. In other words, how do you go from the linked data to the data frame `urban`?

Comment: So the linked data is the data frame that I used. My apologies the Google sheets is named differently. But is exactly what the data frame "urban" is .

Comment: I am trying to read in the data using `read.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14lZajSHqDvDswot8tFh5x6XOAMfmqFkEKZnvsDc_t0c/edit#gid=0",header=TRUE)` but this gives an error. How are you reading the data from the Google doc to R?

Answer (score 0):

remove your `geom_text`, and try to use `library(gghighlight)` with the `use_direct_label = TRUE` parameter